# Encountering PyMuPDF Installation Error in cPanel: Seeking Guidance for Resolution as a Beginner

Tags: python, cpanel, python-wheel, pyproject.toml, pymupdf

I'm currently working on a Python project that involves PyMuPDF for PDF processing. I've successfully written the Python script and have it running as expected on my local development environment. Now, I'm in the process of deploying this script on cPanel, where it will serve its intended purpose.
When I attempt to install Pymupdf within the cPanel terminal using the command "pip install pymupdf," I encountered the following error:

```
Collecting pymupdf==1.22.5
Using cached PyMuPDF-1.22.5.tar.gz (61.6 MB)
Installing build dependencies … done
Getting requirements to build wheel … done
Installing backend dependencies … done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pymupdf
Building wheel for pymupdf (pyproject.toml) … error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for pymupdf (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[73 lines of output\]
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: sys.argv: ['/home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py', 'bdist_wheel', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/pip-wheel-mg640akx/.tmp-r18qslxs']
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: os.getcwd(): /tmp/pip-install-47afuc7u/pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: __file__: /tmp/pip-install-47afuc7u/pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: $PYTHON_ARCH: None
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: os.environ (34):
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     MANPATH: :/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/share/man
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     HOSTNAME: n3plcpnl0084.prod.ams3.secureserver.net
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     TERM: xterm-256color
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     HISTSIZE: 1000
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     USER: pathto
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     LS_COLORS: rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     OPENSSL_NO_DEFAULT_ZLIB: 1
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     VIRTUAL_ENV: /home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     MAIL: /var/spool/mail/pathto
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PATH: /tmp/pip-build-env-edsvupyn/overlay/bin:/tmp/pip-build-env-edsvupyn/normal/bin:/home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/opt/alt/ruby27/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/pathto/.local/bin:/home/pathto/bin
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PWD: /home/pathto/public_html/pdf.weserv.be/public
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     JAVA_HOME: /usr/local/jdk
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     EDITOR: vim
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     LANG: C
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PS1: ((python:3.11)) \[\]\u\[\]@\[\]\h\[\] [\w]\[\]\[\]\$\[\]
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     HISTCONTROL: ignoredups
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     A3_CACHE_SIZE: 4G
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     SHLVL: 1
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     HOME: /home/pathto
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     LS_OPTIONS: --color=tty -F -a -b -T 0
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     LESS: -I -P[\"?f%f:Standard input.\" - ?ltLine %lt?L of %L..?pt (%pt\%).?e (END).]
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     LOGNAME: pathto
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     VISUAL: vim
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     CVS_RSH: ssh
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     CLASSPATH: .:/usr/local/jdk/lib/classes.zip
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     LESSOPEN: ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     G_BROKEN_FILENAMES: 1
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     HISTTIMEFORMAT: %d/%m/%y %T
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     _: /home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11/bin/pip
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     OLDPWD: /home/pathto
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PIP_BUILD_TRACKER: /tmp/pip-build-tracker-p70lxa8_
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PYTHONNOUSERSITE: 1
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PYTHONPATH: /tmp/pip-build-env-edsvupyn/site
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py:     PEP517_BUILD_BACKEND: setuptools.build_meta
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: platform.system()='Linux'
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: sys.platform='linux'
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: PYMUPDF_SETUP_MUPDF_BUILD=None
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: mupdf_tgz already exists: /tmp/pip-install-47afuc7u/pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/mupdf.tgz
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: Extracting /tmp/pip-install-47afuc7u/pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/mupdf.tgz
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: mupdf_local='mupdf-1.22.2-source'
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: Building mupdf.
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: Copying fitz/_config.h to mupdf-1.22.2-source/include/mupdf/fitz/config.h
      pymupdf_7e40f6743aad46ce8053534f66c089dc/setup.py: Building MuPDF by running: cd mupdf-1.22.2-source &&  CFLAGS="-fPIC" make HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLFW=no HAVE_GLUT=no HAVE_LEPTONICA=yes HAVE_TESSERACT=yes verbose=yes build=release build_prefix=pymupdf-x86_64- && echo mupdf-1.22.2-source/build/pymupdf-x86_64-release: && ls -l build/pymupdf-x86_64-release
      mkdir -p build/pymupdf-x86_64-release/source/fitz/ ; cc -fPIC -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pipe -O2 -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer  -Iinclude -MMD -MP -o build/pymupdf-x86_64-release/source/fitz/archive.o -c source/fitz/archive.c -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -Ithirdparty/freetype/include -Iscripts/freetype -Ithirdparty/gumbo-parser/src -Ithirdparty/harfbuzz/src -Ithirdparty/libjpeg -Iscripts/libjpeg -Ithirdparty/lcms2/include -DHAVE_LCMS2MT -Ithirdparty/mujs -Ithirdparty/zlib -Ithirdparty/jbig2dec -Ithirdparty/openjpeg/src/lib/openjp2 -DOPJ_STATIC -DOPJ_HAVE_INTTYPES_H -DOPJ_HAVE_STDINT_H -DHAVE_LEPTONICA -Ithirdparty/leptonica/src -DHAVE_TESSERACT -Ithirdparty/tesseract/include -Iscripts/tesseract -Ithirdparty/extract/include -Ithirdparty/extract/src
      In file included from include/mupdf/fitz.h:76,
                       from source/fitz/archive.c:23:
      include/mupdf/fitz/link.h:64: error: redefinition of typedef 'fz_link'
      include/mupdf/fitz/link.h:31: note: previous declaration of 'fz_link' was here
      make: *** [build/pymupdf-x86_64-release/source/fitz/archive.o] Error 1
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/home/pathto/virtualenv/python/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-edsvupyn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-edsvupyn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-edsvupyn/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 702, in <module>
        File "/opt/alt/python311/lib64/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cd mupdf-1.22.2-source &&  CFLAGS="-fPIC" make HAVE_X11=no HAVE_GLFW=no HAVE_GLUT=no HAVE_LEPTONICA=yes HAVE_TESSERACT=yes verbose=yes build=release build_prefix=pymupdf-x86_64- && echo mupdf-1.22.2-source/build/pymupdf-x86_64-release: && ls -l build/pymupdf-x86_64-release' returned non-zero exit status 2.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymupdf
Failed to build pymupdf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymupdf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've already upgraded pip, setuptools, and wheel using the command "pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel" but still get the same error.
Can someone please advise me on how to resolve this issue?
P.S. I'm a beginner.

Comment: You omitted 73 important lines of output. Please [edit] and return them back.

Comment: Try `pip install --only-binary=pymupdf pymupdf` There're enough wheels at https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/1.22.5/#files

Comment: You should post an issue on PyMuPDF's home page https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF or even you have no / don't want a Github account, ask the question on the public Discord channel https://discord.com/channels/770681584617652264/983871937711341618

Comment: @phd I tried this command I got ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymupdfpip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymupdfpip.....I tried pip install --only-binary=fitz fitz , I get this error :ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects, I tried to install numpy but I got the same error

Comment: Misspelled `pymupdfpip` — it must be `pymupdf`. `numpy` should be installed the same way: `pip install --only-binary=numpy numpy`

Comment: I only misspelled it in the comment , and install --only-binary=numpy numpy is giving the same error , could it be because I run this commands  in virtual environment, @phd

Comment: "*…could it be because I run this commands in virtual environment*"? Shouldn't be. I must admit I don't understand what is going on. From the error message it seems you install on a host with x64 processor, Linux OS, Python 3.11. I don't expect any problems as there're precompiled wheels for `numpy` et al at PyPI.